# Banner Picture for Meta?

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to see a banner on the meta site, as well as the main site - we have room, and we have pictures.

I'd like to suggest that we either use the same picture as the main site, or the "2nd Place" picture.  That way, we have a nice picture on meta as well, and more users get their picture up.

What do you think?

Comment: Hmm... I've been having a hard time keeping up with the main banner, not sure adding a second would help that.

Comment: Haha...  It's my new job opportunity!  $45/hour?  :)

Comment: Honestly, though, you could ask one of the higher rep people (or me- that'd be fine) to do it.  I'm sure you could find quite a few willing helpers.

Comment: You need access to moderator tools to do that. :)

Comment: Aww that's too bad.  Another option might just be to choose a static picture to go there.  The contest picture would be nicer, though.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to have the meta header mirror the main header (so the mods still only have to update one photo). However I tend to agree with Philip below: meta is our behind-the-scenes area, so it shouldn't be flashy.

Comment: Color inverted (negative-esque) of the main site image? (no, I'm not at all serious)

Comment: Haha - a funny twist.  (Actually...)

Comment: ...Not such a bad idea anyways...

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. It was a legitimate request. It may not have been accepted, but no need for anyone to be rude.

Comment: On Meta, usually votes are used to show opinion, so downvotes would mean more people disliked it that liked it.  All the reputation on these sites comes from participation on the main site, and votes on meta mean nothing (reputation-wise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm struggling to see what real benefit this would provide - meta isn't that place which needs to be shiny to attract new users and get them to stay. Let's focus or efforts on things which improve the main site instead.

Comment: I generally agree. It's also worth noting that it requires changes to meta from the SE team, it's not currently a moderator option like it is on the main site.